# httpd -k restart : print some info like " service httpd restart "

Tags: apache, service, httpd.conf

restarting apache via service command :

```
service httpd restart

Stopping httpd: [ OK ] 
Starting httpd: [ OK ]
```

I want to be able to get the same output without using the "service" command.

the following command works but does not print anything.

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
```

Comment: May I ask why? Why don't you just use the service command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "service" command runs the `/etc/init.d/httpd` script, this script restarts httpd and prints the info.

With `/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart`, you are restarting httpd without printing anything.

> I want to be able to get the same output without using the "service" command.

#### Option 1

Run the httpd init script:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

#### Option 2

You could create a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Restarting httpd..."
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
```

Name it '`restart_httpd.sh`', for example, and make it executable:

```
chmod +x restart_httpd.sh
```

Run it:

```
./restart_httpd.sh
```